# Install official released version of Android app as a beta tester

Tags: android, beta

I am a beta tester for an Android app. I joined the beta program and receive updates to test the beta versions.

How can I go back to the official released version of the app?

I don't want to leave the beta program, I just want to install the official version.

On an iPhone you can manage with testflight, which version you want to install. And if you want the official release, you just go to the app store and install the official version from there.

How does this works for Android?

In Google Play Store I do not see any tab "Beta" like discribed in on some google articles. If I navigate to the app in Google Play Store, I don't anything like "leave the beta" too.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Leave the beta program, the following is taken from [Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180?hl=en) and was found in 5 seconds. So there is no way you can

> ## Leave a beta program
>
> **Important:**  When you leave and uninstall a beta app, you may lose your progress and any customizations you made to the app.
>
> - Open the Play Store Google Play.
> - At the top right, tap the profile icon.
> - Tap Manage apps & devices and then Beta.
> - Find the app you want to leave.
> - Tap the app to open its detail page.
> - Under “You’re a beta tester," tap Leave and then Leave.
> - Tip: If you leave an early access or beta program, your space opens up and someone else may take it. You’re not guaranteed to get your
>   space in the beta program back later.
>
> ### Use the app’s public version
>
> - To continue to use the app after you leave the beta program:
> - Uninstall the app. Learn how to uninstall apps.
> - Reinstall the public version of the app. Learn how to reinstall apps.

So there is no way for you to use the app's public version without leaving the program.

Comment: Found that too in 4.5 sec.;-) but as I mentioned, I don't see anything like "you're a beta tester, leave"